# "Село" или "деревня"?

Tags: лингвистика

Как правильно говорить, "село" или " деревня", и есть ли разница между этими понятиями?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Вообще-то, в речи употребляются оба варианта, но есть принципиальная разница. Село - это поселение с церковью, а деревня - без.